# Headless browser is not focusing the element to click in Robot Framework but works without headless

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, google-chrome-headless, selenium2library

```
Click Element   id=inboxfield
Input Text  id=inboxfield
Click Element   xpath=//*[@id="header-1"]/nav/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/span/button
Set Focus To Element    xpath=//*[contains(type(checkbox),'name="table_records"')]
Click Element   xpath=//*[contains(type(checkbox),'name="table_records"')]
```

**Element to click is somewhere on the top and its not clicking and it throws validation as below**

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element xpath=//*[contains(type(checkbox),'name="table_records"')] is not clickable at point (672, 3). Other element would receive the click: <div class="row">...</div>
  (Session info: headless chrome=79.0.3945.130)
```

Comment: The error message is self explanatory: "Other element would receive the click: <div class="row">...</div>", Have you tried taking a screenshot?

Comment: yes @A.Kootstra took a screenshot and it doesn't have the field which I want to click. So I gave scroll & focus and then also it doesn't work

Comment: try movetoElement and click

Comment: Have you tried setting the window size on your headless session to your desktop resolution?

Comment: I dont know how to set it. Do you have any reference ?

Comment: There is a separate keyword for it: [Set Window Size](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Set%20Window%20Size).